# In Angular ui-router nested state url changes,but template is not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router for nested states & views. When I click on the link, the URL changes to the URL for the substate, but the template does not load.

For example, when the URL changes to the substate `project/settings`, the corresponding template `project.settings.html` is not loading.

Here is an SSCCE courtesy of [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RGEapeaYbAAtQYaQXxS0?p=info)

Below is my code as well:

### app.js

```
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
             $stateProvider
                  .state('project', {
                         url: "/project",
                         views:{
                         "content":{templateUrl: "partials/project.html"},
                         "header":{templateUrl: "partials/header"}
                         }
                       })

                  .state('project.settings', {
                          url: "/settings",
                          views:{
                           "content":{templateUrl: "partials/project.settings.html"},
                           "header":{templateUrl: "partials/header"}
                          }
                         }) 
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")                   
   }); 

    /* cheching whether the user is authentic or not*/


 myApp.run(function($rootScope,$location,$cookieStore,validateCookie,$state) {
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event,toState,toParams,fromState){
         if($cookieStore.get('user')){
            validateCookie.authService(function(result,error){
              if(!result){
                 $location.path("/");
              }else{
                $state.go('project.settings');
              }
            });   
         }
         else{
            $location.path("/"); 
         }
        });
    });
```

### index.html

```
                <div ng-controller="userController">
                    <div ui-view="header"></div>
                    <div class="container" ui-view="content"></div>
                </div>
```

### project.html

```
            <div ng-controller="userController">
                <div class="details">
                    <a ui-sref=".settings" class="btn btn-primary">Settings</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

### project.settings.html

```
        <h1>Project Setting -State test</h1>
```

Comment: Any luck with this?  I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all change file name `project.settings.html` in templateurl and file name to `projectSettings.html` (remove dot).

```
   .state('project.settings', {
         url: "/settings",
          views:{
               "content":{templateUrl: "partials/projectSettings.html"},
               "header":{templateUrl: "partials/header"}
           }
    })
```

Add two divs in the project template to load the sub pages (header abd projectSettings)

Note: Any content in this divs will be replaced with the page loaded here.

**project.html**

```
     <div ng-controller="userController">
        <div class="details">
            <a ui-sref=".settings" class="btn btn-primary">Settings</a>
        </div>
        <div ui-view="header">( Project Page header will replace with projectSettings header )</div>
        <div class="container" ui-view="content">( Project Page content will replace with projectSettings Content )</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! After maybe 6 other answers this is the one that got me through.  What was I missing? `Add two divs in the project template`.

Answer (score 23):

Your nested project.settings state needs to address the view in the higher state explicitly using an '@' suffix, ie.:

```
.state('project.settings', {
        url: "/settings",
        views:{
              "content@":{templateUrl: "partials/project.settings.html"},
              "header@":{templateUrl: "partials/header"}
        }
 })
```

See more details here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names

Comment: I was wondering why I had seen the `@` sign.  I think this just opened my eyes.  In my case I needed to use `content@` because the `ui-view` I was using for content was in my `index.html`.  It seems to be working;  I am hoping this is the correct way to do this.

Comment: thank you, although a different issue then described here, your views@ gave me a hint and I realized it was referencing wrong parent.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and the solution was to place ui-view to your parent's template. Because your partials also need a  too, if they will be loading a template from a child state.
See here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#issue-my-templates-are-not-appearing--loading--showing

Answer (score 2):

If using nested views with UI-router, be sure to add ui-view into the html of the parent page and include specific named views.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the solution was; open the **project.html** file (which is the parent page) and wrap everything within `<ui-view>`

So, replace these:

```
<div ng-controller="userController">
  <div class="details">
    <a ui-sref=".settings" class="btn btn-primary">Settings</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

with these:

```
<ui-view>
 <div ng-controller="userController">
   <div class="details">
     <a ui-sref=".settings" class="btn btn-primary">Settings</a>
   </div>
 </div>
</ui-view>
```

and you will be good to go ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ui-sref="project.settings"` for link in `project.html` template.

Comment: already tried replacing .setting with  project.setting .Anyway thanks

Comment: Can you provide working plunker/fiddle (your plunker doesn't seem to work)?

Comment: The code in the plunkr is not a running one, I will improve it.I just thought, it will be helpfull to edit and compile,if anyone  interested.thank you for your  suggestions.