# In Angular ui-router, for nested state, corresponding template is not rendering?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show tab(profile+setting), like the following image, but when i click on any tabs, corresponding template is not loading. In `customerinfo.view.html` I tried to change `<div ui-view="{{tab.view}}"></div>` to `<div ui-view></div>` it causing me infinite digest cycle.

I am able to change the url, When first time we hit the url `http://localhost:3000/home/#/updatecustomer/3/` following time opens, when click on profile, url change to `http://localhost:3000/home/#/updatecustomer/3/profile`, but corresponding template(profile.html) is not loading, same is happening for `setting`

[image]

I go through this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424524/in-angular-ui-router-nested-state-url-changes-but-template-is-not-loading) question, but no help

**Module definition**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngCookies', 'ui.bootstrap']);
    app.config(function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'home/home.view.html',
        })

 .state('home.updatecustomer', {
     url: 'updatecustomer/:customerId/',
     controller: 'TabsDemoCtrl',
     templateUrl: 'addcustomer/customerinfo.view.html',
 })
 .state('home.updatecustomer.profile', {
     url: 'profile',
     controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
     templateUrl: 'addcustomer/profile.html',
 }))
 .state('home.updatecustomer.setting', {
            url: 'setting',
            controller: 'SettingCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'addcustomer/setting.html',
 })
```

**customer.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app');
    app.controller('TabsDemoCtrl', TabsDemoCtrl);
    TabsDemoCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state'];
    function TabsDemoCtrl($scope, $state){
        $scope.customer = 3;
        $scope.tabs = [
            { title:'profile', view:'profile', active:true },
            { title:'setting', view:'setting', active:false }
        ];
    }
})();
```

**customerinfo.view.html**

```
  <uib-tabset active="active">
      <uib-tab  ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}"  active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
         <div ui-view="{{tab.view}}"></div>
      </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

**profile.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app') ;
    app.controller('ProfileCtrl', ProfileCtrl);
    ProfileCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function ProfileCtrl($scope){
         $scope.profile="Profile 123";
    }
})() ;
```

**profile.html**

profile

**Setting.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app') ;
    app.controller('SettingCtrl', SettingCtrl);
    SettingCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function SettingCtrl($scope){
        $scope.setting="setting 1213";
    }
})() ;
```

**setting.html**

setting

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

1) The first thing-- the naming of your urls. Instead of `http://localhost:3000/home/#/updatecustomer/3/` the url should be `http://localhost:3000/#/updatecustomer/3/`

2) You want the tabs to be children of your home state. Do this by setting `abstract: true`.

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        abstract: true,
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: 'home/home.view.html'
    })
```

3) The url for your routes must begin with a `/`.

```
  .state('home.your-splash-view', {
    url: '/home',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'home/splash.view.html'
  })
  .state('home.updatecustomer', {
     url: '/updatecustomer/:customerId/',
     controller: 'TabsDemoCtrl',
     templateUrl: 'addcustomer/customerinfo.view.html'
  })
  .state('home.updatecustomer.profile', {
     url: '/profile',
     controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
     templateUrl: 'addcustomer/profile.html'
  });
```

4) Consider navigating states with the`ui-sref` directive.

Something like:

`<uib-tab ui-sref='home.updatecustomer.profile'> ... </ui-tab>`

Related:

[what is the purpose of use abstract state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423272/what-is-the-purpose-of-use-abstract-state?newreg=8c7e3527eb5942f9a601cf5fb3f9b7a7)

[Why give an "abstract: true" state a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181532/why-give-an-abstract-true-state-a-url)

Comment: edited... hopefully that puts you on the right direction

Comment: we cann't use `abstract:true`, because I need '/home' url